# Bash ping status script

Tags: bash, ping

I've done the following script

```
HOSTS="ns1.server.com ns2.server.com"
SUBJECT="Host Down"

for myHost in $HOSTS
do
count=$(ping -c 10 $myHost | grep 'received' | awk -F',' '{ print $2 }' | awk '{               
print $1 }')
if [ $count -eq 0 ]; then
echo "Host : $myHost is down (ping failed) at $(date)" | sendEmail -f email (email address removed) -u "$SUBJECT" etc etc
fi
done
```

Run via cron every 5 minutes however when a host is down I will receive and email every 5 minutes reflecting this. What i'd like is to add the function so that it only emails me when the status has changed. ie if it's down I don't want it to send any further updates until it's up.

Comment: What about saving the previous result somewhere (in a file) and comparing with the current result?

Comment: yes that's what i want to do but don't know how to code it

Comment: You can use two files: `alive` and `down`. Then for example if it was down and now you detect it is down again, check if the name is in the `down` file.

Comment: can you integrate this into my above code please?

Comment: What i thought like is you run your script with cron at regular intervals and send mail only when the host is down, and then if the mail isn't recieved at next fixed cron period, u r sure that your host is up else keep on getting host down alerter.

Comment: I only want to be alerted of up or down status once otherwise my mailbox will quickly fill up with duplicate alerts being sent every 5 mintues.

Comment: You can use an infinite while loop that is true till the status is ok and breaks once host is down and sending mail henceforth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like this can help:

```
#!/bin/bash

HOSTS="ns1.server.com ns2.server.com"
HOSTS="123.123.1.1 ns1.server.com"
SUBJECT="Host Down"

ping_attempts=1
down_hosts=down_hosts.txt

for myHost in $HOSTS
do
        count=$(ping -c $ping_attempts $myHost | awk -F, '/received/{print $2*1}')
        echo $count
        if [ $count -eq 0 ]; then
                echo "$myHost is down"
                if  [ $(grep -c "$myHost" "$down_hosts") -eq 0 ]; then
                        echo "Host : $myHost is down (ping failed) at $(date)"
                        echo "$myHost" >> $down_hosts
                fi
        else
                echo "$myHost is alive"
                if  [ $(grep -c "$myHost" "$down_hosts") -eq 1 ]; then
                        echo "Host : $myHost is up (ping ok) at $(date)"
                        sed -i "/$myHost/d" "$down_hosts"
                fi
        fi
done
```

Comment: Haha, ``if  [ $(grep -c "$myHost" $down_hosts) -eq 0 ]; then`` is funny. Use ``if [[ grep -q "myHost" "$down_hosts" ]]; then`` instead. This works because if ``grep`` finds anything then the exit code is going to be 0, otherwise 1. Anything greater than 1 is an error. Also, do not forget the quotes around ``"$down_hosts"`` because it will break if ``$down_hosts`` contain any spaces

Comment: @alekx I added your change to the above and got, ./ping.sh: line 15: conditional binary operator expected
./ping.sh: line 15: syntax error near `-q'
./ping.sh: line 15: `                if [[ grep -q "myHost" "$down_hosts" ]]; then'

Comment: I am so sorry. instead of
``if [[ grep -q "myHost" "$down_hosts" ]]; then`` use
``if grep -q "myHost" "$down_hosts"; then`` Because there is no need in [[ ]]

Comment: Using a host that's online, every time the script runs I get an email saying it's online?

Comment: No problem, @Aleks-DanielJakimenko. I rolled back to my previous `grep` condition, leaving the other one commented. Thanks anyway, it is very keen from you suggesting this option.

Comment: @Lurch how come? Try adding an `echo "$myHost is online"` just in the same block of `sed -i` to see if it enters in that condition.

Comment: added that and it outputs ns1.server.com is online I still get an email everytime it's run. also when using 1 online host and 1 offline host I only get emails about the online host and the offline one isn't written to down_hosts.txt

Comment: @Lurch try printing `$count` after it is set. If it is not 0 it shouldn't send any email. Cannot figure out what can be happenning.

Comment: ns1.server.com 1, nothing is output for ns2.server.com

Comment: @Lurch what's the output of ping when it is offline? Mine is `10 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 0ms`, so that the `awk` line returns `0`.

Comment: 10 packets transmitted, 0 received, +9 errors, 100% packet loss, time 9022ms

Comment: @Lurch `echo "10 packets transmitted, 0 received, +9 errors, 100% packet loss, time 9022ms " | awk -F, '/received/{print $2*1}'` returns 0, so count should be 0 in that case.

Comment: don't know whats going on then as nothings being written to down_hosts.

Comment: @Lurch Try copy pasting my whole code again. It worked to me when I did some tests. I am on ubuntu 13.04 and bash 4.2.45.

Comment: copy&pasted, this time no emails and again nothing inserted in file for offline host.

Comment: @Lurch you need to "touch" the file before executing the script for the first time. Otherwise it does not exist and it cannot write in it.

Comment: @Lurch then I don't know what's going on. Try to debug any of the scripts (yours, the one from other solution or mine).

Comment: It did insert the down host in the file in one of your earler revisions.

Comment: your first script enters info into down_hosts.txt

Comment: @Lurch just posted my kind of original script. Check it, I cannot go further.

Comment: now we're getting somewhere, ip is written to down_hosts however it only stores one entry ie if I have HOSTS="10.10.10.1 10.10.10.2 10.10.10.3 and .2 and .3 are offline it only stores .3 in the down_hosts file not ,2 as well.

Comment: Note the good one is `echo "$myHost" >> $down_hosts` which appends. I initially posted `echo "$myHost" > $down_hosts`, which removes previous info.

Comment: thanks, updated i've edited your version to invlude email on host alive but now I get a host alive email every time the script is run not just on status change?

Comment: @Lurch Delete the `sendEmail` part from `echo "Host: $myHost is alive`

Comment: but I want an email when it's alive from being down

Comment: @Lurch check updated answer and replace yourself what is missing.

Comment: AWESOME! works spot on thank you so much for your time and effort @fedorqui and aleks

Comment: It's been my longest "chat" in an answer since I am in [so]! I am glad it finally worked. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

There is a good point in the comments that you might want to use an infinite loop. But as you have asked for something different, here you go:

```
HOSTS="ns1.server.com ns2.server.com"
SUBJECT="Host Down"
PATH_STATUS='/yourfolder/hoststatus_' # For example can be located in /tmp.

for myHost in $HOSTS; do
    count=$(ping -c 10 "$myHost" | grep 'received' | awk -F',' '{ print $2 }' | awk '{ print $1 }')
    [[ -f "$PATH_STATUS$myHost"]] && prevStatus=$(cat "$PATH_STATUS$myHost") || prevStatus='unknown'
    [[ $count == 0 ]] && curStatus='down' || curStatus='up'

    if [[ $curStatus != $prevStatus ]]; then
        echo "$curStatus" > "$PATH_STATUS$myHost"
        echo "Host : $myHost is $curStatus at $(date)" | sendEmail
    fi
done
```

Comment: cat: ns1.server.com: No such file or directory

Comment: This error is going to pop up only once, the first time you start your script. Everything else should work fine. I will make an edit

Comment: Did you change a directory in PATH_STATUS? Does that directory exist?

Comment: yes to /tmp    ./ping.sh: line 9: unexpected token `newline', conditional binary operator expected
    ping.sh line 9: syntax error near `prevStatus='unknown''
    ping.sh: line 9: `    [[ -f "$PATH_STATUS$myHost"]] && prevStatus=$(cat "$PATH_STATUS$myHost") || prevStatus='unknown''

Comment: in that case it must be '/tmp/yourprefix'