# automated scripting telnet or portqry

Tags: perl, powershell, batch-file, telnet, portqry

Need an advise on how to create an automate script to check connectivity from multiple servers to one server (DB) within Windows server environment either with telnet/portqry and also the script will create a .txt file for unsuccessful connection

Thanks in advance for your help
Claudia

Comment: can you use tnsping ?

Comment: What about perl's `Net::Ping`?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just ping it?

```
if ping -q -c 1 yourserver; then
    echo 'server is online'
else
    echo 'server is offline'
fi
```

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18378941/bash-ping-status-script/) question is similar.

This is **bash** because you have used [bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash) tag

If you need to check specific port, then you can use this code:

```
timeout 10 "telnet server port"
if [[ $? == 124 ]]; then # timeout is going to exit with 124 code if it timeouts because of the telnet
    echo 'server is online'
else
    echo 'server is offline'
fi
```

Comment: no cannot use ping as need to have the connectivity to SQL Server port

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at IPSentry.  We've been using it for a number of years in a mixed Windows/UNIX/Linux environment and found it works well.

Comment: we want to avoid to install some tools on our server

Answer (score 0):

Since you claim in the comments that you are really trying to test connectivity into a Sql Server, why not use .Net SqlConnection class? Like so,

```
$server = "server\instance"
$conStr = "Data Source=$server;Integrated Security=true;Initial Catalog=master;Connect Timeout=3;"
$sqlConn = new-object ("Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection") $conStr
try {
    $sqlConn.Open()
    if ($sqlConn.State -eq 'Open') {
        $sqlConn.Close();
        write-host "$server is alive."
    } else {
        write-host "$server connection problem: $($sqlConn.State.ToString())"
    }
} catch {
    write-host "$server is unavailable:"
}
```